# install printer hp

Tags: lubuntu, printing, 15.04

i when click on Print test page , dose'nt work , and when

```
sudo hp-setup
```

i get error :

```
engmmrj@engmmrj-MS-7592:~$ sudo hp-setup

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.15.2)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 Hewlett-Packard Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Searching... (bus=usb, search=(None), desc=0)
error:  The printer you are trying to setup requires a binary driver plug-in and it failed to install.  Please check your internet connection and try again.  Visit  http://hplipopensource.com  for more infomation.
```

model my printer : Hewlett-Packard HP LaserJet Professional M1132 MFP

Screenshot follows:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or)

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this launchpad answer: https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/264941