# How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, scanner

Let's assume that one has some modern HP printer and/or scanner which is  supported by HPLIP package from official repository. Or supported by newer version of HPLIP package (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/66509) about installation).

From official documentation ([*HP Developer Portal | All Supported Printer Models*](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index)) it is known that device needs proprietary/binary driver or plugin.

How should one install such plugin?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For HPLIP from APT make sure that you have installed `hplip-gui` package. If it is not installed - install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install hplip-gui
```

According to [official HP documentation](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/binary_plugin.html) we need to have  HPLIP installed and then install binary plugin as follows.

> To install the plug-in using the GUI you can follow these procedures:
>
> 1. Launch a command-line window and enter:
>
>    ```
>    hp-setup
>    ```
> 2. Select your connection type and click "Next".
> 3. Select your printer from "Selected Devices" list and click "Next".
> 4. Enter your root password when prompted and click "Next".
> 5. Use the recommended installation method and click "Next".
> 6. Check the box to accept with the "Driver Plug-In License Agreement" and click "Next".
> 7. Finish the installation of the printer as normal, however you may be prompted to re-enter your user name and password.
>
> If you run into any additional install problems you can go to our
>   [known issues](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/howtos/known) page and check for a solution.
>
> For advanced users who wish to install HPLIP components manually, a
>   utility exists (hp-plugin) which will download and install the plugin
>   file, but it does not also install a printer queue like hp-setup does.
>
> Do the following:
>
> 1. Launch a command-line window and enter:
>
>    ```
>    hp-plugin
>    ```
> 2. Follow the directions above for navigating the GUI but remember that the printer queue will not be installed through this process.

Comment: Once installed, there is also the HP Toolbox (I can access it with a runner/launcher, its desktop file contains the line `Exec=sh -c 'STARTED_FROM_MENU=yes /usr/bin/hp-toolbox'`) which also provides options to add/remove printers but also many other options and info, like ink levels.

Comment: Fails to complete step 6 on 19.04 with a "failed to download key."  This was immediately fixed by changing apparmor settings, but that is not a good solution.  Will try wiping 19.04 and returning to 18.04 :-/

Answer (score 4):

As a complement to the main answer:

```
hp-setup
```

[image]

There is also

```
hp-toolbox
```

[image]

(it may need refreshing the printers list in order to show all info)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

The scanner doesn't seem accessible though the above GUIs, so **Simple Scan** or alternatives are needed. -- There is Skanlite (cannot save to pdf), Xsane (I find it a bit complicated and oldish, but has a lot of options), VueScan (non-free).

Answer (score 1):

I have just installed the following 5 packages on both Kubuntu 18.04 and Linux Mint 19 systems and been able to print from my HP Laserjet P1505 printer after long trials.

- hplip
- hplip-data
- printer-driver-foo2zjs
- printer-driver-foo2zjs-common
- printer-driver-pxljr

Once you install them all using Muon or Synaptic or (`sudo apt-get install`), you are all set.

Answer (score 1):

On new Ubuntu 19.10 there was a problem: the plug in not won't install no more.

I found a solution [here by zaskar_84 user](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/hplip-keeps-looping-at-plug-in-installation-4175647505/)

I report this here using concrete command to realize it.

```bsh
$ sudo mkdir -p {/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu,/usr/lib64/x86_64-linux-gnu}
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/sane /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sane
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/sane /usr/lib64/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane
$ hp-setup
```

Best regards to zaskar_84