# HP printer P1566

Tags: printing, hplip

I am using ubuntu 14.04 in which I have installed HP printer's latest driver plugin **hplip3.18.7.run** which is working fine for other HP printers *(while suggested by hpdeveloper site min plugin version required for p1566 is 3.10)* but my P1566 printer is taking paper inside and return blank paper as output without printing anything. While toner of printer P1566 is full because when I give test page print from the printer (*there is button in the printer itself for testing print*) it print the test page perfact. Hiw to fix this glitch. please help

Comment: Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 LTS has [hplip 3.14.3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty-updates&searchon=names&keywords=hplip) ([> 3.10](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index)) in the repositories. Why are you trying to install binary driver from HPLIP site? Usually HP devices should work out the box. Are you sure that [binary addon/plugin](https://askubuntu.com/a/1070471/66509) is installed correctly?

Comment: As my system is working fine for other hp printers I can say that plugin is installed correctly. Even though what is another way to install hp printer tell me I will try that too if works fine.