# 18.04 can scan, but not print HP LaserJet Pro MFP M127fn

Tags: 18.04, printing, hp, scanner

Note that I have run through all the suggestions at [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or) and still have the same problem

Running 'Diagnose Queues' says `Queue(s) configured correctly using HPLIP`.

Running 'Diagnose HPLIB Driver' gives the following (which all looks fine to me):

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.18.9)
Self Diagnse Utility and Healing Utility ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.18.9)
Self Diagnse Utility and Healing Utility ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Checking for Deprecated items....
No Deprecated items are found

Checking for HPLIP updates....

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.18.9)
HPLIP upgrade latest version ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Latest version of HPLIP is already installed.

Checking for Dependencies....

---------------
| SYSTEM INFO |
---------------

 Kernel: 4.15.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 16:19:09 UTC 2018 GNU/Linux
 Host: isaac
 Proc: 4.15.0-36-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 16:19:09 UTC 2018 GNU/Linux
 Distribution: 12 18.04
 Bitness: 64 bit

-----------------------
| HPLIP CONFIGURATION |
-----------------------

HPLIP-Version: HPLIP 3.18.9
HPLIP-Home: /usr/share/hplip
HPLIP-Installation: Auto installation is supported for ubuntu distro  18.04 version 

Current contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:
# hplip.conf.  Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.18.9

[dirs]
home=/usr/share/hplip
run=/var/run
ppd=/usr/share/ppd/hplip/HP
ppdbase=/usr/share/ppd/hplip
doc=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.18.9
html=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.18.9
icon=/usr/share/applications
cupsbackend=/usr/lib/cups/backend
cupsfilter=/usr/lib/cups/filter
drv=/usr/share/cups/drv/hp
bin=/usr/bin
apparmor=/etc/apparmor.d
# Following values are determined at configure time and cannot be changed.
[configure]
network-build=yes
libusb01-build=no
pp-build=no
gui-build=yes
scanner-build=yes
fax-build=yes
dbus-build=yes
cups11-build=no
doc-build=yes
shadow-build=no
hpijs-install=no
foomatic-drv-install=no
foomatic-ppd-install=no
foomatic-rip-hplip-install=no
hpcups-install=yes
cups-drv-install=yes
cups-ppd-install=no
internal-tag=3.18.9
restricted-build=no
ui-toolkit=qt4
qt3=no
qt4=yes
qt5=no
policy-kit=no
lite-build=no
udev_sysfs_rules=no
hpcups-only-build=no
hpijs-only-build=no
apparmor_build=yes
class-driver=no

Current contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:
[plugin]
installed = 1
eula = 1
version = 3.18.9

Current contents of '~/.hplip/hplip.conf' file:
[upgrade]
notify_upgrade = true
last_upgraded_time = 1538503165
pending_upgrade_time = 0
latest_available_version = 3.17.10

[settings]
systray_visible = 0
systray_messages = 0

[last_used]
device_uri = "hpfax:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M127fn?serial=CNB9H8T11D"
printer_name = HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M127fn
working_dir = .

[commands]
scan = /usr/bin/xsane -V %SANE_URI%

[refresh]
rate = 30
enable = false
type = 1

[polling]
enable = false
interval = 5
device_list = 

[fax]
voice_phone = 
email_address = 

[installation]
date_time = 2018-10-02 14:58:53
version = 3.18.9

                     

--------------
| COMPILEDEP |
--------------

 gcc                  gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler                         REQUIRED        -               7.3.0           OK         -
 make                 make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs       REQUIRED        3.0             4.1             OK         -
 libtool              libtool - Library building support services                  REQUIRED        -               2.4.6           OK         -

------------------------
| General Dependencies |
------------------------

 libcrypto            libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library                    REQUIRED        -               1.1.0           OK         -
 python-xml           Python XML libraries                                         REQUIRED        -               2.2.5           OK         -
 libnetsnmp-devel     libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files REQUIRED        5.0.9           5.7.3           OK         -
 sane-devel           SANE - Scanning library development files                    REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 pil                  PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan) OPTIONAL        -               1.1.7           OK         -
 pyqt4-dbus           PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4                         REQUIRED        4.0             4.12.1          OK         -
 libpthread           libpthread - POSIX threads library                           REQUIRED        -               2.27            OK         -
 python-devel         Python devel - Python development files                      REQUIRED        2.2             2.7.15          OK         -
 cups-devel           CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files    REQUIRED        -               2.2.7           OK         -
 python-dbus          Python DBus - Python bindings for DBus                       REQUIRED        0.80.0          1.2.6           OK         -
 cups-ddk             CUPS DDK - CUPS driver development kit                       OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 reportlab            Reportlab - PDF library for Python                           OPTIONAL        2.0             3.4.0           OK         -
 pyqt4                PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x)         REQUIRED        4.0             4.12.1          OK         -
 libusb               libusb - USB library                                         REQUIRED        -               1.0             OK         -
 cups-image           CUPS image - CUPS image development files                    REQUIRED        -               2.2.7           OK         -
 python2X             Python 2.2 or greater - Python programming language          REQUIRED        2.2             2.7.15          OK         -
 python-notify        Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 libjpeg              libjpeg - JPEG library                                       REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 sane                 SANE - Scanning library                                      REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -

----------------------
| Scan Configuration |
----------------------

 scanext              Scan-SANE-Extension                                          REQUIRED        -               3.18.9          OK         -
 hpaio                HPLIP-SANE-Backend                                           REQUIRED        -               3.18.9          OK         'hpaio found in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf'

-------------------------
| External Dependencies |
-------------------------

 gs                   GhostScript - PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer REQUIRED        7.05            9.25            OK         -
 scanimage            scanimage - Shell scanning program                           OPTIONAL        1.0             1.0.27          OK         -
 cups                 CUPS - Common Unix Printing System                           REQUIRED        1.1             2.2.7           OK         'CUPS Scheduler is running'
 network              network -wget                                                OPTIONAL        -               1.19.4          OK         -
 policykit            PolicyKit - Administrative policy framework                  OPTIONAL        -               0.105           OK         -
 xsane                xsane - Graphical scanner frontend for SANE                  OPTIONAL        0.9             0.999           OK         -
 dbus                 DBus - Message bus system                                    REQUIRED        -               1.12.2          OK         -
 avahi-utils          avahi-utils                                                  OPTIONAL        -               0.7             OK         -

---------------------
| Python Extentions |
---------------------

 hpmudext             IO-Extension                                                 REQUIRED        -               3.18.9          OK         -
 cupsext              CUPS-Extension                                               REQUIRED        -               3.18.9          OK         -

------------------------------
| DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |
------------------------------

device `hpaio:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M127fn?serial=CNB9H8T11D' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M127fn all-in-one

--------------------------
| DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |
--------------------------

  Device URI                        Model                     
  --------------------------------  --------------------------
  hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M127  HP LaserJet Pro MFP M127fn
  fn?serial=CNB9H8T11D                                        

---------------------------------
| INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |
---------------------------------

 HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M127fn
--------------------------
Type: Printer
Device URI: hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M127fn?serial=CNB9H8T11D
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M127fn.ppd
PPD Description: HP LaserJet Pro MFP m127fn, hpcups 3.18.9
Printer status: printer HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M127fn is idle.  enabled since Tue 02 Oct 2018 02:55:05 PM EDT
Communication status: Good

HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M127fn_fax
------------------------------
Type: Fax
Device URI: hpfax:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M127fn?serial=CNB9H8T11D
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M127fn_fax.ppd
PPD Description: HP Fax2 hpcups
Printer status: printer HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M127fn_fax is idle.  enabled since Tue 02 Oct 2018 02:01:21 PM EDT
Communication status: Good

--------------
| PERMISSION |
--------------

USB             HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M127fn     Required        -        -        OK       Node:'/dev/bus/usb/001/003' Perm:'  root  lp rw- rw- rw- rw- r--'

Checking for Configured Queues....

Queue(s) configured correctly using HPLIP.
Checking for HP Properitery Plugin's....
No plug-in printers are configured.

Diagnose completed...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or)

Comment: @NOrbert thanks for the pointer, but that is exactly what I did :( And the fact that it did not work is why I posted all the diagnostic stuff.

Comment: Please add what you've tried and what was the result. Until then the question *will* be closed as *duplicate* question... feel free to reopen it by editing your question tho.

Comment: The end result was (wish I could remember where I saw this suggestion): 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgs9-common
Then printing worked, but scanning didnt. After that reinstalled hplip _again_, and now I can both print and scan!

Comment: Same problem here with the identical printer .... I will report back if I can solve the issue that +user877841 suggestes regarding reinstalling libgs9-common.