# Installing HP Laser Jet Pro MFP M130nw

Tags: printing, hp

I am trying to install an HP Laser Jet Pro multifunction printer (MFP M130nw) on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, but no success. After connecting it to my PC, there's no printing and scanning. Launching a print from a document, my screen displays a message 'the print has been stopped' while the printer is ON.
Settings>Devices>Printer says the printer is 'Ready'. The printer screen also shows 'Ready'. The Software Center indicates HPLIP is already installed. What could still be missing?
OS type - 64-bit, GNOME 3.28.2, my ease with the Terminal- almost like a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your printer [is supported with HPLIP version](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index), shipped with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. You do not need to install latest binary HPLIP and/or proprietary/binary plugin.

So you need to connect printer to the same network and/or USB then simply install HPLIP with

```
sudo apt-get install hplip-gui
```

then launch the HP setup

```
hp-setup
```

and follow wizard on screen.

Comment: @NOrbert That works! Printing, Scanning and Copying, all is fine. Thanks.

Comment: How does the scan work? I followed hp-setup and it added the printer and the fax but the `hp-scan` command says `No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality`.

Comment: @NaderGhanbari `hp-plugin` may be needed. See [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/1070471/66509) for details.