# Can't install HP Deskjet 2540 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: printing, hp, hplip

I installed `hplip` and `hplip-data`. Then I started HPLIP Toolbox GUI. I click add printer and then I get a message (see pic) that `PPD` file is not found. When I click browse I find some .gz file and none of them solve the issue if selected.

[image: HP Device Manager Setup dialog]

Then

[image: select PPD file dialog]

My Ubuntu is Ubuntu 18.04

The output of `apt-cache policy hplip hplip-gui`:

```
hplip:
  Installed: 3.17.10+repack0-5
  Candidate: 3.17.10+repack0-5
  Version table:
 *** 3.17.10+repack0-5 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
hplip-gui:
  Installed: 3.17.10+repack0-5
  Candidate: 3.17.10+repack0-5
  Version table:
 *** 3.17.10+repack0-5 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Following [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097937/installing-hp-laser-jet-pro-mfp-m130nw), I did:

1. `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui`
2. `hp-setup`

I get a GUI for HP Device Manager. My printer is connected by USB. So I select **USB** then <kbd>Next</kbd>. Then I move to another page with title **Select from Discovered Device**, which shows my printer listed. I click on my printer and <kbd>Next</kbd>. Then I get this in the terminal.

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.17.10)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Searching... (bus=usb, search=(None), desc=0)
error: No PPD found for model deskjet_2540 using old algorithm.
error: No appropriate print PPD file found for model deskjet_2540_series
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Please add output of `apt-cache policy hplip hplip-gui` to the question. According to [HPLIP page](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) you need at least 3.13.8 without proprietary driver/plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing HP Laser Jet Pro MFP M130nw](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097937/installing-hp-laser-jet-pro-mfp-m130nw)

Comment: @N0rbert plz see my edit. Plz provide details on how to solve the issue?

Comment: Make sure you have installed `hplip-data` package, then run `hp-setup` and follow the wizard guidance.

Comment: `hplip-data` is installed. Plz see EDIT 2 for desription of what I get.

Comment: " and none of them solve the issue if selected." well they clearly have "fax" in the name so that should not be a surprise.  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/driverless.1.html can be used to create a ppd but I do not know what the succes rate is for that

Answer (score 4):

It should simply work without PPD file. It is not declared in `/usr/share/hplip/data/models/models.dat` even in latest HPLIP 3.19.3.

So you need to install all HPLIP stuff with

```
sudo apt-get install hplip-gui hpijs-ppds
```

and then follow `hp-setup` wizard.

If `hp-setup` fails, then try install all known printer drivers with

```
sudo apt-get install printer-driver-all
```

and use `system-config-printer`.

Comment: I followed every step. When I run `system-config-printer` I click "Add" button it asks for authentication to fetch device (it seems for network printers).  But my printer is USB.