# HP printer/scanner not working after 22.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, printing, hp, scanner

I recently upgraded from 20.04 LTS to 22.04.1 LTS through online upgrade process. Since then, the HP printer/scanner LaserJet Pro MFP M130nw doesn't print or scan.

The 'Document Scanner' detects the printer though but nothing happens on launch leaving 'Unable to scan' message.

What should I do? (My ease on Linux : newbie)

Thnx.

OS name:Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS; OS Type: 64-bit; GNOME version: 42.2

Comment: what tool are you using to scan? The default `Document Scanner`?

Comment: It may be necessary to add the printer from scratch see https://linuxhint.com/how-to-add-printers-ubuntu/

Comment: USB we imagine. You will want to give us what you get for `systemctl status ipp-usb` and `lpstat -t`.

Comment: @brian_pkam@kam-G41M-Combo:~$ systemctl status ipp-usb
○ ipp-usb.service - Daemon for IPP over USB printer support
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ipp-usb.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:ipp-usb(8)

Comment: @brian_p Here's the report. https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=22587359#p22587359 (The 1st post, text in black)

Comment: @kamyogi make it an answer, upvote, accept and in 6 days reward the bounty to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Resolved with this reply. [Installing HP Laser Jet Pro MFP M130nw](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097937/installing-hp-laser-jet-pro-mfp-m130nw). I had to execute these commands this time too. The printer works fine.