# Unable to scan in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, usb, hp, scanner

I have problem with scanning on LJ M1132 MFP printer/scaner. My search on many various forums did not get anywhere so I try to ask directly if someone can help me.

I recently reinstall system from Mate 16.04. to Ubuntu 18.04. In 16.04. the scanner had no problems. After installation of new system I had problems even with the printing. I installed newest hplip. Printing works for some time but scanning was not possible. All the time it show i/o problems.

For example "simple scan" shows warning 
"*Unable to connect to scanner*".

If I run

> hp-scan

it comes with 
"*error: SANE: Error during device I/O (code 9)*"

I try several tips, like reinstalling hplip, so now I have instaled 3.18.6 version, but no change in scanning.

If I run

> hp-check -t

from my point important part of output is

```
-----------------------
| HPLIP CONFIGURATION |
-----------------------

HPLIP-Version: HPLIP 3.18.6
HPLIP-Home: /usr/share/hplip
HPLIP-Installation: Auto installation is supported for ubuntu distro  18.04 version 

Current contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:
# hplip.conf.  Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.18.6

----------------------
    | Scan Configuration |
    ----------------------

     scanext              Scan-SANE-Extension                                          REQUIRED        -               3.18.6          OK         -
     hpaio                HPLIP-SANE-Backend                                           REQUIRED        -               3.18.6          OK         'hpaio found in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf'


    ------------------------------
    | DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |
    ------------------------------

    device `hpaio:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Professional_M1132_MFP?serial=000000000QH6ADT0PR1a' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_LaserJet_Professional_M1132_MFP all-in-one

    --------------------------
    | DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |
    --------------------------

      Device URI                        Model                           
      --------------------------------  --------------------------------
      hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Professional  HP LaserJet Professional M1132  
      _M1132_MFP?serial=000000000QH6AD  MFP                             
      T0PR1a                                                            
    --------------
    | PERMISSION |
    --------------

    USB             HP_LaserJet_Professional_M1132_MFP Required        -        -        OK       Node:'/dev/bus/usb/005/005' Perm:'  root  lp rw- rw- rw- rw- r--'
    No errors or warnings.
```

As was suggested to install Plug-in, it is already installed together with the hplip. Even for printing my printer needs Plug-in. For versions of hplip 13.16.9 and 13.18.6 which were installed on my computer (together with similar version of plug-in) printing was working but scaner no. And my printer is not the latest model, according to the https://developers.hp.com my printer should be supported with hplip from version 3.10.4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or) - you need to install proprietary driver/plugin for your device (see [HPLIP support page](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index)).

Comment: As was suggested to install Plug-in, it is already installed together with the hplip. Even for printing my printer needs Plug-in. For versions of hplip 13.16.9 and 13.18.6 which were installed on my computer (together with similar version of plug-in) printing was working but scaner no. And my printer is not the latest model, according to the https://developers.hp.com my printer should be supported with hplip from version 3.10.4.