# 18.04 hplip problem

Tags: 18.04, printing, hp, scanner

I have tried to install hplip 3.18.12 on my machine since the upgrade to 18.04.  The printer will install and work fine.  However, I cannot use the scanner function.  I am always notified that a plugin is required  When I attempt to install the plugin through any means I have tried so far, I get this error: *Python gobject/dbus may be not installed*.

Before you jump on me, please notice that I have searched the postings extensively.  The only post I can find is this one:  *Can't print and can't install hp-plugin [duplicate]* where everyone indicates that it's a duplicate and has been addressed previously.  The fact that it is a duplicate is fine.

Assuming that is true, please tell me/us where it was addressed before.  I cannot locate anything that works to get past this error and not pointing to the previous posting is not helpful in any way.

Thank you,

Comment: About scanner - you may need to install proprietary driver/plugin - see other [question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/1070470/66509). Also make sure that really need to install latest binary HPLIP (check minimal required HPLIP version on [HP page](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index)). If minimal version is available in the repository - uninstall binary and install one with APT.

Comment: I have the same problem (printer perfect, but plugin installation for scanner is failing) it looks like it is caused by not being able to get the key for the plugin from the server pgp.mit.edu

I have to clue how to circumvent that, because without the key it refuses to install

Comment: And no, the linked answers do not help and this question is NOT a duplicate!

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Please help

Comment: @CalamityJane I think this https://askubuntu.com/a/1250782/707756 would help you.