# HP-Plugin fail , HPLIP

Tags: hplip

I use Ubuntu  16.04 LTS . HPLIP 3.16.3 comes with this .  I have bought a new printer  LaserJet Pro MFP M130nw   which requires a minimum of HPLIP 3.16.11.

I downloaded from the HP Developer website  the Automatic   Installer (.run file  ) Download   HPLIP 3.20.5 . and then  ran the Automatic Installer .

The process went well until  the HP-PLUGIN  failed  -see log below

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.20.5)
Plugin Installer ver. 3.0
Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.
Plug-in version: 3.20.5
Installed HPLIP version: 3.20.5
Number of files to install: 64
Plugin installation failed
error: Python gobject/dbus may be not installed
error: Plug-in install failed.
Done.
```

A newbie question  - how do I install  “Python gobject/dbus “ ?

Comment: `sudo apt install python-gobject` should work. IIRC there is number of packages that HPLIP depends on which do not get installed automatically this way. `python-gobject` may only be the first of the series. But hang on, eventually it will get installed.

Comment: @jos                                                                                                                        That That has not worked.                                                                                                *jm@jm-OptiPlex-9020:~$ sudo apt install python-gobject
[sudo] password for jm:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-gobject is already the newest version (3.20.0-0ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
jm@jm-OptiPlex-9020:~$*

Comment: According [to HP](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) - you device does not require plugin. It should simply work.

Comment: @N0rbert . I agree that according to HP the device does not require a plugin . The printer works but the scanner does not .   When I try to scan I receive a message from the HP device manager " Driver Plugin required "

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me . Now  Plug-in installation successful .

Install apparmor utils

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils
```

Run

```
sudo aa-disable /usr/share/hplip/plugin.py
```

Run as normal user, not as root:

```
hp-plugin
```

Comment: The suggested answer worked for me with Laserjet MP M148dw

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this does and why it works?