# simple scan very slow contacting scanner

Tags: 18.04, printing, hp, scanner

I set up my HP M44fdw scan/fax/print multi function device using `hp-setup` installed via `apt`, following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HpAllInOne). Printing works as expected.

I'd like to use network scanning, too. I'm using `hp-toolbox` to kick off `simple-scan` with the correct `hpaio` scanner URI. Everything works as expected, except for the *five minute wait* when I click the green "Scan" button. It pauses showing this:

[image]

Any ideas on how to speed up this bit?

I'm using 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop. It does *not* repro on a 2nd computer running 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop that was installed from scratch, so I'm wondering if there's some cache/legacy carryover from a previous version of some program. I tried blowing away `~/.cache/simple-scan/` but that didn't help. I also tried uninstalling and purging `hplip`, `cups`, `simple-scan`, and `xsane`. I tried temporarily disabling `ufw`. I deleted all print queues and re-added the one for the HP. No change.

```
$ hp-diagnose_plugin 

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.17.10)
Diagnose Plugin Utility ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Device Plugin is already installed
```

Comment: According to [HPLIP page](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) you need to have at least version 3.15.11 (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has 3.17, so it is OK) with proprietary [plugin installed](https://askubuntu.com/a/1070471/66509). Do you have driver plug-in installed? To determine your HPLIP version and plugin status please add output of `hp-diagnose_plugin` to the question.

Comment: ok, added output of `hp-diagnose_plugin`

Comment: The output seems to be correct, may be network issue.