# Printing stopped for HP-1102 series after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, printing

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 my HP-1102w printer stopped working. I get the following Printing Stopped.
I restart the job multiple times, and it looks like it's printing, however after a while I get the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or) - your printer need proprietary driver (plugin) - see [official table](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index).

Comment: @N0rbert It is not a duplicate. I get this error as well, having installed hplip from the information in the link you provide, where no such "Printing Stopped" error is mentioned (as of the date of this comment).