# Getting printer and duplexer to work on Ubuntu 18.04 for Laserjet 1020

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, hplip

I am trying to get my HP Laser-Jet 1020 to work with my Ubuntu 18.04 installation. I have successfully installed `hplip` from HP's official website, but it does not seem to work as Ubuntu seems to like the foomatic driver more and will refuse to print on any other driver than that. I have tried to do change the make and model to hplip 3.19.1 from printer properties, but it will no longer work. I made sure that I had all dependencies. I also did `hp-setup -i`, both interactive and trought GUI, with similar results. The plugins were installed successfully, same for the setup and firmware, but at best, the printer will only print one-sided documents. There are no installable options in the printer properties and there is no duplexer installed check-box to be checked.(except when i try to use hplip 3.19 with the proprietary plugin, but that does not even print) In all other apps, the double sided printing option is disabled (grayed out). Any suggestions ?

P.S. I did: `sudo apt-get purge hplip` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get autoclean`, just so I can start clean.

Other funny thing was that although I installed hplip 3.19., `dpkg -l hplip` was still displaying version 3.17 installed.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or)

Comment: It seems that you messed up deb-packaged and binary versions of HPLIP - follow [**uninstallation** part of my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/66509), then install HPLIP from repository. Your printer is pretty old, but it needs [proprietary plugin](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index). So you should follow the [related Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/1070470/66509).

Comment: I have already checked out that post @N0rbert. I will see if the second link gives any results. P.S. I have tried a bunch of solutions already posted on this topic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried all the suggestions listed above, but neither of them worked. Instead, I went and grabbed an older version from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/). (you can also find this link by clicking on more info on the main page, than choosing older version from the bottom of the page)

Although this enabled the duplexer and installable options, it did not stop the printing process so I can manually print on both sides. It is still better than the latest version. (3.19.1 at this time)