# HP Device manager : Plug-in install failed

Tags: hp, scanner, laserjet

My HP Laserjet Pro MFP M26nw worked fine with Ubuntu 16.04 but since I installed 18.04 only the print function works, I cannot get the scan function to work.

Simple Scan says "failed to scan" and the HP Device manager tells me: Driver required.

Clicking next returns: Failed to install plugin.

Running hp-plugin from the terminal and downloading returns: failed to load module "canberra-gtk.module". Plug-in installation failed.

Does anyone know how to solve this? I have the latest version of HPLIP.

Comment: hi! how does ubuntu 18.10 fare?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or) (as you device really [needs plugin](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index)). About Canberra -install it with `sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module`.

Comment: Thanks, I did this and now the canberra error does not appear anymore. But the HP plugin still does not work:

Comment: This is what the terminal returns:Plug-in version: 3.19.1
Installed HPLIP version: 3.19.1
Number of files to install: 64

Plugin installation failed
error: Python gobject/dbus may be not installed
error: Plug-in install failed.