# How to install HP OfficeJet Pro 6970 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: printing, dependencies

I made a boo-boo.

I bought a new HP OfficeJet Pro 6970, without first verifying if it works with Ubuntu 18.04.  Of course, it does not.

```
INSTALL MISSING REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
-------------------------------------
note: Installation of dependencies requires an active internet connection.
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: cups-devel (CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libtool (libtool - Library building support services)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: cups-image (CUPS image - CUPS image development files)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: libnetsnmp-devel (libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: pyqt4-dbus (PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: pyqt4 (PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x))
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: dbus (DBus - Message bus system)
warning: Missing REQUIRED dependency: sane-devel (SANE - Scanning library development files)


INSTALL MISSING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCIES
-------------------------------------
note: Installation of dependencies requires an active internet connection.
warning: Missing OPTIONAL dependency for option 'fax': reportlab (Reportlab - PDF library for Python)
warning: Missing OPTIONAL dependency for option 'scan': pil (PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan))
warning: This installer cannot install 'pil' for your distro/OS and/or version.
```

All the recommended repositories are active, which doesn't matter as the missing dependencies above are no longer available with 18.04.

Yes, I am running the latest version  of hplip-3.19.3

This is where I get stuck:

```
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcups2-dev'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Command failed. Re-try #1...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcups2-dev'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Command failed. Re-try #2...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcups2-dev'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Command failed. Re-try #3...
Running 'sudo apt-get install --assume-yes libcups2-dev'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: Package install command failed with error code 100
Would you like to retry installing the missing package(s) (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ?
```

Any life-saving... okay money-saving advice out there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or)

Comment: Hey there you nailed my question perfectly... I installed the gui and now everything seems to work...THX

Comment: I've added this as answer to you question for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you make sure that you have installed hplip-gui package. If it is not installed - install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install hplip-gui
```

Acknowledgements to N0rbert and his reply to a similar question [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or)

Comment: For binary installation this is not enough. See my answer. Deb package and binary can't coexist in the same time because of [the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/1782137).

Comment: @N0rbert IIRC when I followed your post a short time ago to fix a problem accessing my new HP printer, in the process, it asked if the old version should be removed which I answered in the affirmative and it worked perfectly as opposed to removing it manually.

Comment: @ Grahah. Thank you for feedback. I'll recheck my guide for mistakes or discrepancies.

Comment: @N0rbert not so much a mistake or discrepancy but an addition to your extremely helpful guide. Earlier advice suggested removing the old Deb package first before installing the binary but the process of downloading/installing the binary actually took care of it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [hplip official page](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index) you have to install at least HPLIP 3.16.8, so the package from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (version 3.17.10) would be enough.

The proprietary driver/plugin is not required for your printer.

Then consider to follow **Uninstallation** part of [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/66509) to remove unnecessary binary version of HPLIP:

> ```
> sh hplip-3.19.3.run --noexec
> cd hplip-3.19.3
> sudo ./uninstall.py
> sudo rm -rf /usr/share/hplip/
> ```
>
> Afterwards we install official Ubuntu packages instead (optionally):
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install hplip-gui
> ```

and run `hp-setup` (see exact steps in [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1070471/66509)).