# laserjet m1132 plugin ubuntu

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, plugins

I've installed `hplip-3.19.3.run` on my Ubuntu 16.04 to use my LaserJet M1132 MFP and the driver was installed, but it keeps asking for an installation of proprietary plugin. I downloaded the plugin from the HP site and passing it through a existing location but the installation always fails:

[image: Unable to receive key from server]

[image: Plug-in install failed]

I tried to run the plugin file through the terminal:

```
root@pc:/home/user/Downloads# sh hplip-3.19.3-plugin.run
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing HPLIP 3.19.3 Plugin 
Self Extracting Archive..............................................................

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.19.3)
Plugin Installer ver. 3.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Plug-in version: 3.19.3
Installed HPLIP version: 3.19.3
Number of files to install: 64


Done.
```

But I'm still getting the installation required plugin message.

[image]

Still no printing... It seems that the printer getd the print command  but the paper is blank.

*Can anyone can help me?*

Comment: I own exactly the same model, it needs [at least HPLIP 3.10.4](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index); it works great with both deb-packaged HPLIP (3.16 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) and binary one. For this device the driver package consists of two components: open-source and binary addon/plugin. So it is possible duplicate of [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or).

Comment: I could find HPLIP 3.10.4 version available to download... then I downloaded HPLIP 3.10.5.run file available on https://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/3.10.5/

I follow the steps according to https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/install/install/index

And get stock on make install part... 

Running 'make'
Please wait, this may take several minutes...
error: 'make' command failed with status code 2

Answer (score 0):

I'll write complete explanation here to make things more clear.

Really you do not need binary driver package from HPLIP SourceForge site.

If you have already downloaded, then remove it with and setup MFP with steps below:

1. Navigate to the folder where `hplip-3.19.3.run` saved.

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   ```
2. Remove this HPLIP 3.19.3 from the system if was installed with

   ```
   sh hplip-3.19.3.run --noexec
   cd hplip-3.19.3
   sudo ./uninstall.py
   sudo rm -rf /usr/share/hplip/
   ```
3. Then install HPLIP deb-package with APT from the repository:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository universe
   sudo apt-get install hplip-gui
   ```
4. Launch HPLIP setup

   ```
   hp-setup
   ```

   and follow wizard steps:

   > 1. Select your connection type and click "Next".
   > 2. Select your printer from "Selected Devices" list and click "Next".
   > 3. Enter your root password when prompted and click "Next".
   > 4. Use the recommended installation method and click "Next".
   > 5. Check the box to accept with the "Driver Plug-In License Agreement" and click "Next".
   > 6. Finish the installation of the printer as normal, however you may be prompted to re-enter your user name and password.
5. And finally install the HPLIP binary plugin/addon:

   ```
   hp-plugin
   ```
6. Enjoy!