# Cannot install HP printer: plugin installation not successful

Tags: printing, hp, hardware, hplip

I am trying to set up my HP LaserJet P1102 on Ubuntu 19.04.

I know the [theoretical procedure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or) to install the printer, but this procedure does not work for me, following the "correct" procedure to install the printer (the software + the plugin) fails as follows.

I have downloaded and installed hplip 3.19.5 from [here](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing).

At first the installation seems to succeed. It asks for plugin to be installed, then it says "Plugin installation successful". But after I click OK on this message, it returns to the window in which I should choose which printer to install, and another message pops up:

> error:  The device you are trying to setup requires a binary plug-in. Some functionalities may not work as expected without plug-ins. Please run 'hp-plugin' as normal user to install plug-ins. Visit http://hplipopensource.com  for more infomation.
>
> error: hp-setup failed. Please run hp-setup manually.

Comment: Run `hp-check` and see if any error messages come up. In most cases `hplip` needs some more packages to function, and it can't install these by itself. You might be getting a number of `error: 'libxxx' package is missing/incompatible` messages. If so, simply do `sudo apt install libxxx` and try again.

Comment: @N0rbert I am sorry but it really isn't. Your link explains the procedure to install the plugins, the point is that this procedure (neither the basic one nor the advanced one) works for me

Comment: @raffamaiden I was really assured that HPLIP from deb-package is stable and usable, but it is buggy. So I retracted close-vote / duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or)

Comment: I found help with this issue [via a query on launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/703182). Worth noting here, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same here. I solved this way:

please run:

```
hp-setup -g &> ~/hp-setup.log
```

after your error read the log:

```
cat ~/hp-setup.log
```

you will find some lines like:

hp-setup[19265]: debug: Either /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hp2000S1.so file is not present or symbolic link is missing

if you run:

```
locate libsane-hp2000S1
```

you will get the right place like:

- /usr/lib/sane/libsane-hpgt2500-x86_64.so.1.0.22
- /usr/lib/sane/libsane-hpgt2500-x86_64.so.1.0.27
- /usr/lib/sane/libsane-hpgt2500.so
- /usr/lib/sane/libsane-hpgt2500.so.1
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hpgt2500.so
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-hpgt2500.so.1
- /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-hpgt2500-x86_64.so.1.0.22
- /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-hpgt2500-x86_64.so.1.0.27
- /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-hpgt2500.so
  /usr/lib64/sane/libsane-hpgt2500.so.1

now you only have to make a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu

sudo ln -s /usr/lib64 /usr/lib64/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

run again hp-setup

done

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. On a side note, you can run `cat hp-setup.log | grep "file is not present"` to discover exactly which files are not found. For me, the line to run was `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib64`. For some reasons, hp-lip seems to look for the libraries into `/usr/lib64/x86_64-linux-gnu` instead of the correct `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. May it is worth to report that as a bug.

Comment: It seems that bug was already reported as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hplip/+bug/1825717 . So HPLIP from Ubuntu 19.04 deb-package is buggy (it is [other bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hplip/+bug/1837312) I have reported now).

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know why this worked, but it did. Good job boys!

Answer (score 5):

I also had the problem where the HP printer installs fine but the scanner plugin does not install (Ubuntu 19).Disabling the plugin.py worked!!! (thank you) but I had to install apparmor-utils first.

```
sudo apt install apparmor-utils
sudo aa-disable /usr/share/hplip/plugin.py
hp-plugin
```

The last step runs the HP Plugin installer which is needed for printer scanning to work.

Comment: same issue on Ubuntu 22.04 and this fixed it | Wiki: "AppArmor is a Linux kernel security module that allows the system administrator to restrict programs' capabilities with per-program profiles.". Standard repo, no extra repos needed. Ubuntu page on AppArmor: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-apparmor ; **apparmor-utils is an official sub-package**.

Answer (score 1):

I had a slightly different problem. My HP Printer installed fine, but the scanner plugin would not install properly. It seems the trick was to get AppArmor to lower its shields for a Python script.

**Edit:** Looking at other answers, it looks like it is common to not have AppArmor utils installed, so you may also need to install it first

```
sudo apt install apparmor-utils

sudo aa-disable /usr/share/hplip/plugin.py
```

After I did this, the plugin installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After following [Kai Kramer's answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1159808/22904) I got:

```
error: Python gobject/dbus may be not installed
error: Plug-in install failed.
```

AND

```
cannot access '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state': No such file or directory
```

A search on the web got me to try the following and it worked:

```
$ aa-disable /usr/share/hplip/plugin.py

Command 'aa-disable' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install apparmor-utils
```

**Install apparmor utils (mind you I didn't have it installed!!!)**

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils
```

**Then run**

sudo aa-disable /usr/share/hplip/plugin.py

**& the run as normal user, not as root:**

```
hplip-plugin
```

Now my printer (laserjet 1020) was installed.

Source: [https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/1813768](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/1813768/comments/8)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue for setting up printer HP P1006 in Ubuntu 22.04
Solved by this answer
https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/552897-Hplip-plugin-checksum-error

```
cd
wget https://developers.hp.com/sites/default/files/hplip-3.22.6-plugin.run -O hplip-3.22.6-plugin.run
wget https://developers.hp.com/sites/default/files/hplip-3.22.6-plugin.run.asc -O hplip-3.22.6-plugin.run.asc
hp-plugin --plugin=~/ -i
```