# My printer prints two pages, then the rest are blank

Tags: 16.04, printing, hp

My configuration:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- HP Color Laserjet PRO MFP M176N
- HPLIP 3.18.12

Whenever I print something, it prints only two pages, the rest are blank pages.

Interestingly, after the second page, the printer starts making a strange noise (like there is something stuck inside), however, the pages are still printed.

When we do the same from windows OS it prints perfectly :-(

What should I do to fix that?

**EDIT:** Hplip 3.19.11 also gives me the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or) as you need [HPLIP 3.13.11](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index#note8) with binary/proprietary driver/plugin. So run `hp-plugin` and ping me back if it fails.

Comment: I will try and ping you. Thank you so much.