# New HP Printer - Does not see scanner

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, scanner

I purchased a new Laser Jet pro MPF 148fdw specifically because HP is supposed to be Linux friendly.  I loaded the driver (https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip)  Uubuntu 18.04 sees the printer as wireless and can print.  It also recognizes it as a fax but not a scanner.  Simple Scan can see it but can not scan.  (scan works fine on two windows systems)  I see some bug reports on line that I do not understand.  Probing with my system I several errors that imply the plug in is not loaded, yet it prints.  See below.  Any ideas on this?

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:127: RuntimeWarning: PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK

set_interactive(1)




error: Failed to install Plug-in.
Either you have chosen to skip the Plug-in installation  or entered incorrect Password.

Checking Permissions....


Checking for Configured Queues....
warning: Device Canon-MX860-series is not HPLIP installed. Device must use the hp: or hpfax: to function in HPLIP.
warning: Canon-MX860-series is not HP Device.
unknown protocol device_uri=ipps://NPI966F14.local:631/ipp/print

Queue(s) configured correctly using HPLIP.


Checking for HP Properitery Plugin's....
No plug-in printers are configured.

Diagnose completed...



More information on Troubleshooting,How-To's and Support is available on http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html


Please close this terminal manually. 


Diagnose Plugin Utility ver. 1.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Segmentation fault
error: Failed to install Plug-in.
Either you have chosen to skip the Plug-in installation  or entered incorrect Password.

Done.

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.20.3)
HP Device Manager ver. 15.0

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

\# Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or)

Comment: When I follow the recommended procedure, the machine is added as a printer and Fax but not a scanner.