# i want to install HP printer driver

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

i want to install hplip driver on my ubuntu mate. my printer is HP Laserjet Pro MFP M125a . i install hplip-gui but is not working . pleas help me.
Ubuntu mate 18.04

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or) as your device [needs it](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete How To: [What is the HPLIP Binary Plug-In and How Do I Install It?](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/binary_plugin.html). It includes **HP LaserJet Pro MFP m125a**.
It says:

> Most Linux distributions include HPLIP with their software, but most
>   do not include the plug-in.  Therefore, it is a safe practice to run a
>   utility called "hp-setup", which, will install the printer into the
>   CUPS spooler, download, and install the plug-in at the appropriate
>   time.
>
> To install the plug-in using the GUI you can follow these procedures:
>
> 1. Launch a command-line window and enter:
>
>    ```
>                       hp-setup
>    ```
> 2. Select your connection type and click "Next".
> 3. Select your printer from "Selected Devices" list and click "Next".
> 4. Enter your root password when prompted and click "Next".
> 5. Use the recommended installation method and click "Next".
> 6. Check the box to accept with the "Driver Plug-In License Agreement" and click "Next".
> 7. Finish the installation of the printer as normal, however you may be prompted to re-enter your user name and password.
>
> If you run into any additional install problems you can go to our
>   known issues page and check for a solution.
>
> For advanced users who wish to install HPLIP components manually, a
>   utility exists (hp-plugin) which will download and install the plugin
>   file, but it does not also install a printer queue like hp-setup does.
>
> Do the following:
>
> 1. Launch a command-line window and enter:
>
>    ```
>                   hp-plugin
>    ```
> 2. Follow the directions above for navigating the GUI but remember that the printer que will not be installed through this process.
>
>    *Note: you may need to run hp-plugin as root or super user depending
>      on your distro.