# Ubuntu 20.04 HP M125a scanner problem

Tags: 20.04, hp, scanner

I have an HP USB LaserJet MFP printer/scanner M125a. I installed the printer using hp-update and it works. For scanning I tried to use simple-scan. It opens the GUI and finds the scanner. However when I click the "scan" button it says "Unable to connect to scanner". Tried both as root and user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or) - install `hplip-gui` and run `hp-plugin`

Comment: Just ran "hp-plugin -i", and then "simple-scan" worked!