# Unable to connect to scanner

Tags: networking, scanner

This seems to be a reoccurring problem.  There has been other questions similar to this without a decent answer.  Ubuntu 20.04.1 locates the scanner when Document Scanner starts up but when told to scan it fails with "Failed to scan Unable to connect to scanner".  The scanner is a HP LaserJet M1522nf network connected which worked without problems under 19.10.  The printer portion works just fine.  This is a straight upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04.1.  Xsane fails with "Failed to open device 'hpaio:/usb/HP_LaserJet_M1522nf_MPF? serial=00CNC986V086':Error during device I/O"

What changed between 19.10 and 20.04 that would affect scanners?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think my setup is different, but I can network scan from all 4 of my 20.04 clients. But I am running a raspberry pi as the print server(18.04) with a Canon scanner attached to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or)

Comment: Your scanner is *"network connected"*, but your xsane error is *"hpaio:/usb/HP_LaserJet_M1522nf_MPF? serial=00CNC986V086':Error during device I/O"*. Plug the scanner into a USB port and it should work.

Comment: for the NObert comment, The correct plugin for the scanner is installed (but the scanner still does not work).  About the heynnema comment, -- plugging the scanner into a usb port would probably work, but I need the printer/scanner network connected since I have several computers that use it and not all are on all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Install and be happy:

```
sudo apt install sane-airscan ipp-usb
```

Why these are not part of the regular installation routine, I have no idea.

When installed, scanning works normally. When not, apparently some scanners still work, but many do not. Perhaps a bug report is in order.

Comment: Unable to locate both packages

Comment: @SelfDot, what distro?
Check with 'apt list sane-airscan ipp-usb'
Should see both in output.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.5. 'apt list sane-airscan ipp-usb' gives the result "Listing... Done"

Comment: @SelfDot, this shows a more general problem of being unable to update your system. Once that's fixed, you should be able to install these packages and have scanning work.

A few things to try:
'sudo apt update' should return a dozen sequentially numbered lines and summary info. If not, then your sources would likely need updating (servers could be down).

Once able to update successfully, then adding these packages should be no problem.

Comment: If you're saying 'sudo apt update' should fix the problem, it did not. If you're saying 'sudo apt update' should tell me further things to do to fix my inability to install these packagaes, then maybe you're right, but I don't know how to take all this information and figure out what is wrong. I've got 60+ lines of info.

Comment: @SelfDot, since you're unable to fetch updates, there's a connection problem caused by either your Internet connection or source configuration. You might try running 'software-properties-gtk', click the 'Restore the default settings' button, then retry the update. If successful, then do a 'sudo apt upgrade', then install the scanner fix here. If not, it would be best to open a separate thread since the trouble is unrelated to this one. Best of luck!