# HP Printer Scanner stopped Scanning

Tags: printing, hp, ip-scanner

I have a HP LaserJet Pro M148f-M149f and was using the HP software for printing and scanning on 18.04.5 LT.  All worked well since April but the scan functions now says failed to open device.  When I continue in device manager, it leads to "Failed to install Plug-in.
Either you have chosen to skip the Plug-in installation or entered incorrect Password." and stops.  The print portion works but there are several warnings about the fax portion not installing  (I will not use the fax portion so would prefer it not to be there.  The printer itself recently had a software update so that is suspect.  Any recommendations or is there a way to remove and start over?  Something seems wrong with the plug-in or access to the plug-in

`hp-check` yields

```
Saving output in log file: /home/dan/hp-check.log

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.20.3)
Dependency/Version Check Utility ver. 15.1

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Note: hp-check can be run in three modes:
1. Compile-time check mode (-c or --compile): Use this mode before compiling the
HPLIP supplied tarball (.tar.gz or .run) to determine if the proper dependencies
are installed to successfully compile HPLIP.                                    
2. Run-time check mode (-r or --run): Use this mode to determine if a distro    
supplied package (.deb, .rpm, etc) or an already built HPLIP supplied tarball   
has the proper dependencies installed to successfully run.                      
3. Both compile- and run-time check mode (-b or --both) (Default): This mode    
will check both of the above cases (both compile- and run-time dependencies).   

Check types:                                                                    
a. EXTERNALDEP - External Dependencies                                          
b. GENERALDEP - General Dependencies (required both at compile and run time)    
c. COMPILEDEP - Compile time Dependencies                                       
d. [All are run-time checks]                                                    
PYEXT SCANCONF QUEUES PERMISSION                                                

Status Types:
    OK
    MISSING       - Missing Dependency or Permission or Plug-in
    INCOMPAT      - Incompatible dependency-version or Plugin-version

 
---------------
| SYSTEM INFO |
---------------

 Kernel: 4.15.0-112-generic #113-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 9 23:41:39 UTC 2020 GNU/Linux
 Host: Pavilion
 Proc: 4.15.0-112-generic #113-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 9 23:41:39 UTC 2020 GNU/Linux
 Distribution: 12 18.04
 Bitness: 64 bit


-----------------------
| HPLIP CONFIGURATION |
-----------------------

HPLIP-Version: HPLIP 3.20.3
HPLIP-Home: /usr/share/hplip
HPLIP-Installation: Auto installation is supported for ubuntu distro  18.04 version 

Current contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:
# hplip.conf.  Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.20.3

[dirs]
home=/usr/share/hplip
run=/var/run
ppd=/usr/share/ppd/hplip/HP
ppdbase=/usr/share/ppd/hplip
doc=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.20.3
html=/usr/share/doc/hplip-3.20.3
icon=/usr/share/applications
cupsbackend=/usr/lib/cups/backend
cupsfilter=/usr/lib/cups/filter
drv=/usr/share/cups/drv/hp
bin=/usr/bin
apparmor=/etc/apparmor.d
# Following values are determined at configure time and cannot be changed.
[configure]
network-build=yes
libusb01-build=no
pp-build=no
gui-build=yes
scanner-build=yes
fax-build=yes
dbus-build=yes
cups11-build=no
doc-build=yes
shadow-build=no
hpijs-install=no
foomatic-drv-install=no
foomatic-ppd-install=no
foomatic-rip-hplip-install=no
hpcups-install=yes
cups-drv-install=yes
cups-ppd-install=no
internal-tag=3.20.3
restricted-build=no
ui-toolkit=qt4
qt3=no
qt4=yes
qt5=no
policy-kit=no
lite-build=no
udev_sysfs_rules=no
hpcups-only-build=no
hpijs-only-build=no
apparmor_build=yes
class-driver=no


Current contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:
Plugins are not installed. Could not access file: No such file or directory

Current contents of '~/.hplip/hplip.conf' file:
[upgrade]
notify_upgrade = true
last_upgraded_time = 1588463542
pending_upgrade_time = 0
latest_available_version = 3.17.10

[settings]
systray_visible = 0
systray_messages = 0

[last_used]
device_uri = "hp:/net/HP_LaserJet_Pro_M148f-M149f?ip=192.168.1.200"
printer_name = HP_LaserJet_Pro_M148f-M149f
working_dir = /home/dan/Documents/software installation - make____[install-confdir] Error 1 - Ask Ubuntu_files/hplip-3.20.6-plugin.run

[commands]
scan = /usr/bin/xsane -V %SANE_URI%

[refresh]
rate = 30
enable = false
type = 1

[polling]
enable = false
interval = 5
device_list = 

[fax]
voice_phone = 
email_address = 

[installation]
date_time = 08/26/2020 08:42:25
version = 3.20.3


 <Package-name>        <Package-Desc>      <Required/Optional> <Min-Version> <Installed-Version> <Status>   <Comment>

--------------
| COMPILEDEP |
--------------

 gcc                  gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler                         REQUIRED        -               7.5.0           OK         -
 make                 make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs       REQUIRED        3.0             4.1             OK         -
 libtool              libtool - Library building support services                  REQUIRED        -               2.4.6           OK         -

------------------------
| General Dependencies |
------------------------

 libcrypto            libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library                    REQUIRED        -               1.1.1           OK         -
 python-xml           Python XML libraries                                         REQUIRED        -               2.2.5           OK         -
 libnetsnmp-devel     libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files REQUIRED        5.0.9           5.7.3           OK         -
 sane-devel           SANE - Scanning library development files                    REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 pil                  PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan) OPTIONAL        -               5.1.0           OK         -
 pyqt4-dbus           PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4                         REQUIRED        4.0             4.12.1          OK         -
 libpthread           libpthread - POSIX threads library                           REQUIRED        -               2.27            OK         -
 python-devel         Python devel - Python development files                      REQUIRED        2.2             2.7.17          OK         -
 cups-devel           CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files    REQUIRED        -               2.2.7           OK         -
 python-dbus          Python DBus - Python bindings for DBus                       REQUIRED        0.80.0          1.2.6           OK         -
 cups-ddk             CUPS DDK - CUPS driver development kit                       OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 reportlab            Reportlab - PDF library for Python                           OPTIONAL        2.0             3.4.0           OK         -
 pyqt4                PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x)         REQUIRED        4.0             4.12.1          OK         -
 libusb               libusb - USB library                                         REQUIRED        -               1.0             OK         -
 cups-image           CUPS image - CUPS image development files                    REQUIRED        -               2.2.7           OK         -
 python2X             Python 2.2 or greater - Python programming language          REQUIRED        2.2             2.7.17          OK         -
 python-notify        Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications OPTIONAL        -               -               OK         -
 libjpeg              libjpeg - JPEG library                                       REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 sane                 SANE - Scanning library                                      REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -

----------------------
| Scan Configuration |
----------------------

 scanext              Scan-SANE-Extension                                          REQUIRED        -               3.20.3          OK         -
 hpaio                HPLIP-SANE-Backend                                           REQUIRED        -               3.20.3          OK         'hpaio found in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf'

-------------------------
| External Dependencies |
-------------------------

 gs                   GhostScript - PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer REQUIRED        7.05            9.26            OK         -
 scanimage            scanimage - Shell scanning program                           OPTIONAL        1.0             1.0.27          OK         -
 cups                 CUPS - Common Unix Printing System                           REQUIRED        1.1             2.2.7           OK         'CUPS Scheduler is running'
 network              network -wget                                                OPTIONAL        -               1.19.4          OK         -
 policykit            PolicyKit - Administrative policy framework                  OPTIONAL        -               0.105           OK         -
 xsane                xsane - Graphical scanner frontend for SANE                  OPTIONAL        0.9             0.999           OK         -
 dbus                 DBus - Message bus system                                    REQUIRED        -               1.12.2          OK         -
 avahi-utils          avahi-utils                                                  OPTIONAL        -               0.7             OK         -

---------------------
| Python Extentions |
---------------------

 hpmudext             IO-Extension                                                 REQUIRED        -               3.20.3          OK         -
 cupsext              CUPS-Extension                                               REQUIRED        -               3.20.3          OK         -

------------------------------
| DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |
------------------------------

device `hpaio:/net/HP_LaserJet_Pro_M148f-M149f?ip=192.168.1.200' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_LaserJet_Pro_M148f-M149f all-in-one
device `airscan:HP LaserJet Pro M148fdw (966F14)' is a AirScan HP LaserJet Pro M148fdw (966F14) eSCL network scanner


--------------------------
| DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |
--------------------------

No devices found.

---------------------------------
| INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |
---------------------------------

 
HP_LaserJet_Pro_M148f-M149f
---------------------------
Type: Printer
Device URI: hp:/net/HP_LaserJet_Pro_M148f-M149f?ip=192.168.1.200
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/HP_LaserJet_Pro_M148f-M149f.ppd
PPD Description: HP LaserJet Pro M148f-M149f Postscript (recommended)
Printer status: printer HP_LaserJet_Pro_M148f-M149f is idle.  enabled since Wed 26 Aug 2020 08:20:32 AM PDT
Communication status: Good


--------------
| PERMISSION |
--------------

No errors or warnings.

Done.
dan@Pavilion:~$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or)

Comment: No,  I can delete the printer but when I reload it, installation hangs at the fax install.  the printer gets installed but no scanner.  Trying to scan gets to this error - Failed to open device ‘hpaio:/net/HP_Laserjet_Pro_M148f-M149f?ip=192.168.1.200’:Error during device I/O.