# Scanning failure with HP DeskJet F2410 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, hp, scanner, hplip

I connected an HP DeskJet F2410 All-in-one Printer/Scanner through USB to my laptop running Ubuntu 20.04.  Running the Document Scanner 3.36.3 detected the scanner as HP DeskJet F2400 Series, however pressing [Scan] only activated scanning in the program and the scanner doesn't scan.

Running `hp-check -`t reported the following:

```
narcissan@narcissan-GF63-8RC:~$ hp-check -t
Saving output in log file: /home/narcissan/hp-check.log

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.20.3)
Dependency/Version Check Utility ver. 15.1

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

Note: hp-check can be run in three modes:
1. Compile-time check mode (-c or --compile): Use this mode before compiling the
HPLIP supplied tarball (.tar.gz or .run) to determine if the proper dependencies
are installed to successfully compile HPLIP.                                    
2. Run-time check mode (-r or --run): Use this mode to determine if a distro    
supplied package (.deb, .rpm, etc) or an already built HPLIP supplied tarball   
has the proper dependencies installed to successfully run.                      
3. Both compile- and run-time check mode (-b or --both) (Default): This mode    
will check both of the above cases (both compile- and run-time dependencies).   

Check types:                                                                    
a. EXTERNALDEP - External Dependencies                                          
b. GENERALDEP - General Dependencies (required both at compile and run time)    
c. COMPILEDEP - Compile time Dependencies                                       
d. [All are run-time checks]                                                    
PYEXT SCANCONF QUEUES PERMISSION                                                

Status Types:
    OK
    MISSING       - Missing Dependency or Permission or Plug-in
    INCOMPAT      - Incompatible dependency-version or Plugin-version

warning: ubuntu-20.04 version is not supported. Using ubuntu-19.10 versions dependencies to verify and install...

---------------
| SYSTEM INFO |
---------------

 Kernel: 5.4.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 4 19:50:52 UTC 2020 GNU/Linux
 Host: narcissan-GF63-8RC
 Proc: 5.4.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 4 19:50:52 UTC 2020 GNU/Linux
 Distribution: ubuntu 20.04
 Bitness: 64 bit

-----------------------
| HPLIP CONFIGURATION |
-----------------------

HPLIP-Version: HPLIP 3.20.3
HPLIP-Home: /usr/share/hplip
warning: HPLIP-Installation: Auto installation is not supported for ubuntu distro  20.04 version 

Current contents of '/etc/hp/hplip.conf' file:
# hplip.conf.  Generated from hplip.conf.in by configure.

[hplip]
version=3.20.3

[dirs]
home=/usr/share/hplip
run=/var/run
ppd=/usr/share/ppd/hplip/HP
ppdbase=/usr/share/ppd/hplip
doc=/usr/share/doc/hplip
html=/usr/share/doc/hplip-doc
icon=no
cupsbackend=/usr/lib/cups/backend
cupsfilter=/usr/lib/cups/filter
drv=/usr/share/cups/drv
bin=/usr/bin
apparmor=/etc/apparmor.d
# Following values are determined at configure time and cannot be changed.
[configure]
network-build=yes
libusb01-build=no
pp-build=no
gui-build=yes
scanner-build=yes
fax-build=yes
dbus-build=yes
cups11-build=no
doc-build=yes
shadow-build=no
hpijs-install=yes
foomatic-drv-install=yes
foomatic-ppd-install=no
foomatic-rip-hplip-install=no
hpcups-install=yes
cups-drv-install=yes
cups-ppd-install=no
internal-tag=3.20.3
restricted-build=no
ui-toolkit=qt5
qt3=no
qt4=no
qt5=yes
policy-kit=yes
lite-build=no
udev_sysfs_rules=no
hpcups-only-build=no
hpijs-only-build=no
apparmor_build=no
class-driver=no


Current contents of '/var/lib/hp/hplip.state' file:
Plugins are not installed. Could not access file: No such file or directory

Current contents of '~/.hplip/hplip.conf' file:
[installation]
date_time = 09/20/20 00:24:11
version = 3.20.3


 <Package-name>        <Package-Desc>      <Required/Optional> <Min-Version> <Installed-Version> <Status>   <Comment>

-------------------------
| External Dependencies |
-------------------------

 error: cups          CUPS - Common Unix Printing System                           REQUIRED        1.1             -               INCOMPAT   'CUPS may not be installed or not running'
 gs                   GhostScript - PostScript and PDF language interpreter and previewer REQUIRED        7.05            9.50            OK         -
 error: xsane         xsane - Graphical scanner frontend for SANE                  OPTIONAL        0.9             -               MISSING    'xsane needs to be installed'
 scanimage            scanimage - Shell scanning program                           OPTIONAL        1.0             1.0.29          OK         -
 error: dbus          DBus - Message bus system                                    REQUIRED        -               1.12.16         MISSING    'DBUS may not be installed or not running'
 policykit            PolicyKit - Administrative policy framework                  OPTIONAL        -               0.105           OK         -
 network              network -wget                                                OPTIONAL        -               1.20.3          OK         -
 avahi-utils          avahi-utils                                                  OPTIONAL        -               0.7             OK         -

------------------------
| General Dependencies |
------------------------

 error: libjpeg       libjpeg - JPEG library                                       REQUIRED        -               -               MISSING    'libjpeg needs to be installed'
 error: cups-devel    CUPS devel- Common Unix Printing System development files    REQUIRED        -               -               MISSING    'cups-devel needs to be installed'
 error: cups-image    CUPS image - CUPS image development files                    REQUIRED        -               -               MISSING    'cups-image needs to be installed'
 libpthread           libpthread - POSIX threads library                           REQUIRED        -               b'2.31'         OK         -
 error: libusb        libusb - USB library                                         REQUIRED        -               1.0             MISSING    'libusb needs to be installed'
 sane                 SANE - Scanning library                                      REQUIRED        -               -               OK         -
 error: sane-devel    SANE - Scanning library development files                    REQUIRED        -               -               MISSING    'sane-devel needs to be installed'
 error: libnetsnmp-devel libnetsnmp-devel - SNMP networking library development files REQUIRED        5.0.9           -               MISSING    'libnetsnmp-devel needs to be installed'
 error: libcrypto     libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptographic library                    REQUIRED        -               1.1.1           MISSING    'libcrypto needs to be installed'
 python3X             Python 2.2 or greater - Python programming language          REQUIRED        2.2             3.8.2           OK         -
 error: python3-notify2 Python libnotify - Python bindings for the libnotify Desktop notifications OPTIONAL        -               -               MISSING    'python3-notify2 needs to be installed'
 error: python3-pyqt4-dbus PyQt 4 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt4                         OPTIONAL        4.0             -               MISSING    'python3-pyqt4-dbus needs to be installed'
 error: python3-pyqt4 PyQt 4- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x)         REQUIRED        4.0             -               MISSING    'python3-pyqt4 needs to be installed'
 python3-dbus         Python DBus - Python bindings for DBus                       REQUIRED        0.80.0          1.2.16          OK         -
 python3-xml          Python XML libraries                                         REQUIRED        -               2.2.9           OK         -
 python3-devel        Python devel - Python development files                      REQUIRED        2.2             3.8.2           OK         -
 python3-pil          PIL - Python Imaging Library (required for commandline scanning with hp-scan) OPTIONAL        -               7.0.0           OK         -
 python3-reportlab    Reportlab - PDF library for Python                           OPTIONAL        2.0             3.5.34          OK         -

--------------
| COMPILEDEP |
--------------

 error: libtool       libtool - Library building support services                  REQUIRED        -               -               MISSING    'libtool needs to be installed'
 gcc                  gcc - GNU Project C and C++ Compiler                         REQUIRED        -               9.3.0           OK         -
 make                 make - GNU make utility to maintain groups of programs       REQUIRED        3.0             4.2.1           OK         -

---------------------
| Python Extentions |
---------------------

 cupsext              CUPS-Extension                                               REQUIRED        -               3.20.3          OK         -
 hpmudext             IO-Extension                                                 REQUIRED        -               3.20.3          OK         -

----------------------
| Scan Configuration |
----------------------

'/etc/sane.d/dll.d/hpaio' not found.
 hpaio                HPLIP-SANE-Backend                                           REQUIRED        -               3.20.3          OK         'hpaio found in /etc/sane.d/dll.conf'
 scanext              Scan-SANE-Extension                                          REQUIRED        -               3.20.3          OK         -

------------------------------
| DISCOVERED SCANNER DEVICES |
------------------------------

device `hpaio:/usb/Deskjet_F2400_series?serial=CN9AG1201405H4' is a Hewlett-Packard Deskjet_F2400_series all-in-one


--------------------------
| DISCOVERED USB DEVICES |
--------------------------

  Device URI                        Model                  
  --------------------------------  -----------------------
  hp:/usb/Deskjet_F2400_series?ser  HP Deskjet F2400 series
  ial=CN9AG1201405H4                                       

---------------------------------
| INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES |
---------------------------------

 
Deskjet-F2400-series
--------------------
Type: Printer
Device URI: hp:/usb/Deskjet_F2400_series?serial=CN9AG1201405H4
PPD: /etc/cups/ppd/Deskjet-F2400-series.ppd
warning: Failed to read /etc/cups/ppd/Deskjet-F2400-series.ppd ppd file
PPD Description: 
Printer status: printer Deskjet-F2400-series is idle.  enabled since Saturday, September 19, 2020 PM11:28:05
Communication status: Good


--------------
| PERMISSION |
--------------

USB             Deskjet-F2400-series           Required        -        -        OK       Node:'/dev/bus/usb/001/002' Perm:'  root  lp rw- rw- rw- rw- r--'
 
-----------
| SUMMARY |
-----------

Missing Required Dependencies
-----------------------------
error: 'libcups2' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libdbus-1-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libjpeg-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libcups2-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'cups-bsd' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'cups-client' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libcupsimage2-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libusb-1.0.0-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libusb-0.1-4' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libsane-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libsnmp-dev' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'snmp-mibs-downloader' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'openssl' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'python3-pyqt4' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'gtk2-engines-pixbuf' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libtool' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'libtool-bin' package is missing/incompatible 

Missing Optional Dependencies
-----------------------------
error: 'gtk2-engines-pixbuf' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'xsane' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'python3-notify2' package is missing/incompatible 
error: 'python3-dbus.mainloop.qt' package is missing/incompatible 

Total Errors: 14
Total Warnings: 0

Done.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or)

Comment: i tried that, but the problem remained.