# Scan with hplip for HP Envy 5055 printer only scans bottom 1.5 inches of scanned document

Tags: scanner, hplip, xsane

Running Ubuntu 18.04.4
Printer is HP Envy 5055.
I installed hplip for printer control which works fine for printing.
The HP printer manager has an option to scan in the Action menu.
When I choose scan, it actually runs xsane.  The printer is identified and a preview window displays the entire 8.5x11 document.  However, when I run the scan, the image is only 8.5x1.5.
I have tried getting help with this from hplip development site but there has been no response to my query after two weeks.
The online documentation for xsane is so sparse I can't determine if there is anything I can do to expand the area that is being scanned or increase the size of the image being created.
I expect to scan only simple documents and photos or graphics for images that I want to post online.
Has anyone been able to use xsane with this printer?
Is there another simpler scan software that is worth trying?

Comment: Have you tried to run `hp-plugin` ?

Comment: As far as I can determine, hp-plugin is for Android.  It can also be used with Windows (?), but not with Linux.

Comment: Wrong. See [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/1070470/66509) with example of real usage.

Comment: Have reviewed the hplip web site and the instructions regarding hp-plugin.  My printer is not listed as requiring this plugin.  Eveything listed there is laser which I do not have.  Even so, that Q&A states that hplip doesn't do the scanning.  It just calls a scan program such as xsane.  This problem is with xsane not with hplip.

Answer (score 1):

After much additional reading of documentation, supported devices lists, etc., I've come to the conclusion that xsane doesn't support my printer.  I've installed Simple Scan, which is working just fine.  I'll have to reconfigure my preferences in hplip if I want to scan from within that GUI.  But I don't know that I'll bother.  It's just as easy to launch Simple Scan.