# Problem with wireless printer HP OfficeJet Pro 8710

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, hp

I've been trying to wirelessly connect a printer to my Ubuntu computer. The computer detects the printer and adds it to the list of printers, but some weird things happen:

- The computer has 3 instances of the printer on the list of printers, each of which has a slightly different name and description.
- When I try to use any of the 3 instances to print something, it will not print, even though it gives me the notification that it is printing something on that printer.

**Ubuntu Version**: 20.04

**Printer**: HP OfficeJet Pro 8710

**Instance names**:

- HP-OfficeJet-Pro-8710-AE7B1C
- HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8710_AE7B1C_
- HP_OfficeJect_Pro_8710_AE7B1C_@(random numbers and characters).local

Output of `lpstat -l -e`:

```
HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8710_AE7B1C_ network none ipps://HP%20OfficeJet%20Pro%208710%20%5BAE7B1C%5D._ipps._tcp.local/
HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8710_AE7B1C_@HPB4B686AE7B1C.local permanent ipp://localhost/printers/HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8710_AE7B1C_@HPB4B686AE7B1C.local implicitclass://HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8710_AE7B1C_%40HPB4B686AE7B1C.local/
```

Output of `avahi-browse -art | grep -A 2 -i hostname.*office`

```
Failed to resolve service 'HP OfficeJet Pro 8710 [AE7B1C]' of type '_ipp._tcp' in domain 'local': Timeout reached
Failed to resolve service 'HP OfficeJet Pro 8710 [AE7B1C]' of type '_ipp._tcp' in domain 'local': Timeout reached
Failed to resolve service 'HP OfficeJet Pro 8710 [AE7B1C]' of type '_ipps._tcp' in domain 'local': Timeout reached
Failed to resolve service 'HP OfficeJet Pro 8710 [AE7B1C]' of type '_ipps._tcp' in domain 'local': Timeout reached
```

Output of `avahi-browser -art | grep -B 1 -i hostname.*office`

```
Failed to resolve service 'HP OfficeJet Pro 8710 [AE7B1C]' of type '_ipps._tcp' in domain 'local': Timeout reached
Failed to resolve service 'HP OfficeJet Pro 8710 [AE7B1C]' of type '_ipps._tcp' in domain 'local': Timeout reached
Failed to resolve service 'HP OfficeJet Pro 8710 [AE7B1C]' of type '_ipp._tcp' in domain 'local': Timeout reached
Failed to resolve service 'HP OfficeJet Pro 8710 [AE7B1C]' of type '_ipp._tcp' in domain 'local': Timeout reached
```

I'm really confused and hope someone can help me out!

Comment: Did you install hplip?

Comment: you have tagged canon as your printer but your question seems to realte to HP??? Please [edit] accordingly.

Comment: Printer: HP OfficeJet Pro? Anything more specific than that?

Comment: Provide the names of the three instances and the output of `lpstat -l -e`.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, hplip is installed to the newest version.

Comment: @brian_p I have provided more information per your requests.

Comment: @User24601 I have changed the tags. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

`lpstat -l -e` has an entry for `HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8710_AE7B1C_`.

This has been has been discovered by CUPS itself. You should be able to print with `lp -d "HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8710_AE7B1C_" /etc/nsswitch.conf`. Can you?

You can also set up a print queue if the IP address of the printer is known. It can be found from the printer's front panel. A URI is needed to substitute in the next command. It is `ipp://IP_ADDRESS/ipp/print`. ipps may be used instead of ipp.

Now execute `lpadmin -p PRINTER_NAME -v URI -E -m everywhere`

PRINTER_NAME can be what you want, such as pro8710. Test printing with `lp -d PRINTER_NAME /etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: Nothing printed.

Comment: Let's see if we can get a working print queue from a manual setup. Give `avahi-browse -art | grep -A 2 -i hostname.*office` and `avahi-browse -art | grep -B 1 -i hostname.*office`

Comment: I've added the output of each command. Nothing printed, it all timed out.

Comment: avahi-browse being unable to resolve a service is generally a network issue, such as a firewire rule. I will adjust my answer to attempt to bypass this.

Comment: "firewire" should be "firewall".

Answer (score 0):

You may get more debug information with this command from [hplip package](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing)

```
hp-check -t
```

This checks the system and dependencies then displays a complete report

You should also have a look to `hplip-gui`, which gives a more complete installation process than the basic Linux software

Answer (score 0):

Check out these pages and previous answer.

[HPPrinterInstallation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HPPrinterInstallation)

[HpAllInOne](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HpAllInOne)

[How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or)

In my experience with my laserjets: after running `sudo hp-setup -i` and `hp-check`. It was necessary to install a few more packages and libs to get printer functions such as fax and scanning to work correctly. You may find using `apt search <whatever dependency you may need>` helpful to resolve missing dependency errors that may appear after using `hp-check` as [iaeiou](https://askubuntu.com/users/1144685/iaeiou) suggested.

Also make sure to check any firewall settings that may interfere with detection. Temporarily disable them while you configure the printer.
If you use UFW:

`systemctl status ufw`

`sudo systemctl stop ufw`

Then allow necessary rules for the printer

`sudo ufw allow CUPS`

To start it back up:

`sudo systemctl start ufw`