# i can't install hplip plugin

Tags: printing, hp, scanner, plugins, hplip

when installing hplip plugin form the terminal i get this output :

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.20.11)
Plugin Download and Install Utility ver. 2.1

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

warning: It is not recommended to run 'hp-plugin' in a root mode.

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.20.11)
Plugin Download and Install Utility ver. 2.1

Copyright (c) 2001-18 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

(Note: Defaults for each question are maked with a '*'. Press <enter> to accept the default.)


------------------------------------------
| PLUG-IN INSTALLATION FOR HPLIP 3.20.11 |
------------------------------------------

  Option      Description                                       
  ----------  --------------------------------------------------
  d           Download plug-in from HP (recommended)            
  p           Specify a path to the plug-in (advanced)          
  q           Quit hp-plugin (skip installation)                

Enter option (d=download*, p=specify path, q=quit) ? d

-------------------
| DOWNLOAD PLUGIN |
-------------------

Checking for network connection...
Downloading plug-in from: 
Downloading plug-in: [\                                   ] 0%     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/password.py", line 85, in get_distro_name
    os_name = platform.dist()[0]
AttributeError: module 'platform' has no attribute 'dist'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hp-plugin", line 363, in <module>
    status, plugin_path, error_str = pluginObj.download(plugin_path, plugin_download_callback)
  File "/usr/share/hplip/installer/pluginhandler.py", line 254, in download
    core = core_install.CoreInstall()
  File "/usr/share/hplip/installer/core_install.py", line 241, in __init__
    self.passwordObj = password.Password(ui_mode)
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/password.py", line 118, in __init__
    self.__readAuthType()  # self.__authType
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/password.py", line 141, in __readAuthType
    distro_name = get_distro_name().lower().replace(" ","")
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/password.py", line 88, in get_distro_name
    os_name = distro.linux_distribution()[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distro.py", line 122, in linux_distribution
    return _distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distro.py", line 677, in linux_distribution
    self.version(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distro.py", line 737, in version
    self.lsb_release_attr('release'),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distro.py", line 899, in lsb_release_attr
    return self._lsb_release_info.get(attribute, '')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distro.py", line 552, in __get__
    ret = obj.__dict__[self._fname] = self._f(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distro.py", line 1012, in _lsb_release_info
    stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=devnull)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 153, in apport_excepthook
    with os.fdopen(os.open(pr_filename,
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/crash/_usr_share_hplip_plugin.py.0.crash'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/password.py", line 85, in get_distro_name
    os_name = platform.dist()[0]
AttributeError: module 'platform' has no attribute 'dist'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/hp-plugin", line 363, in <module>
    status, plugin_path, error_str = pluginObj.download(plugin_path, plugin_download_callback)
  File "/usr/share/hplip/installer/pluginhandler.py", line 254, in download
    core = core_install.CoreInstall()
  File "/usr/share/hplip/installer/core_install.py", line 241, in __init__
    self.passwordObj = password.Password(ui_mode)
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/password.py", line 118, in __init__
    self.__readAuthType()  # self.__authType
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/password.py", line 141, in __readAuthType
    distro_name = get_distro_name().lower().replace(" ","")
  File "/usr/share/hplip/base/password.py", line 88, in get_distro_name
    os_name = distro.linux_distribution()[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distro.py", line 122, in linux_distribution
    return _distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distro.py", line 677, in linux_distribution
    self.version(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distro.py", line 737, in version
    self.lsb_release_attr('release'),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distro.py", line 899, in lsb_release_attr
    return self._lsb_release_info.get(attribute, '')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distro.py", line 552, in __get__
    ret = obj.__dict__[self._fname] = self._f(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/distro.py", line 1012, in _lsb_release_info
    stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=devnull)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('lsb_release', '-a')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: Did you install the driver with `sudo`? There are some "permission denied" messages in those errors.

Comment: i did sudo hp-plugin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or) with HPLIP as deb-package from default repository.

Answer (score 0):

Download your plugin version from [openprinting](https://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/auxfiles/HP/plugins/) and install with `sh hplip-<version>-plugin.run`

Comment: my printer is hp color laserjet pro mfp m176n, what plugin do i install ?

Comment: `dpkg -l hplip` gives you the hplip version. Get a plugin for the same version.