# Can't get the HP scanner working in Ubuntu20.04 + Can't install hplip in Ubuntu20.04

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, scanner

I've just got a **HP DeskJet Ink Advantage 2336 All-in-One Printer**.

And turns out, they [don't have support](https://support.hp.com/my-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-deskjet-ink-advantage-2300-all-in-one-printer-series/30334413/model/30334414) for any Linux system. I'm on Ubuntu20.04LTS.

I checked on: https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/hplip-web/plugin.html. It was all empty.

Although the printer is working, I can't scan any documents. Can anyone help me with this?

But I followed this: https://idroot.us/install-hplip-ubuntu-20-04/

And it keeps giving me this:

```
MISSING DEPENDENCIES
--------------------
Following dependencies are not installed. HPLIP will not work if all REQUIRED dependencies are not installed and some of the HPLIP features will not work if OPTIONAL dependencies are not installed.
Package-Name         Component            Required/Optional   
pyqt5-dbus           gui_qt5              OPTIONAL            
reportlab            fax                  OPTIONAL            
pyqt5                gui_qt5              REQUIRED            
python-notify        gui_qt5              OPTIONAL            
Do you want to install these missing dependencies (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ?
```

But these dependencies are already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pyqt5 is already the newest version (5.14.1+dfsg-3build1).
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary  plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or) . You need HPLIP 3.20.5 according [to HP](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index). Try to use simple commands like `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui; hp-plugin` instead of binary installer. If fail - use [other answer about binary hplip](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/66509).

Answer (score 1):

This is the right plugin page: https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/plugins

You need to install the one that matches the hplip version you installed.

As N0rbert says, the minimum version of hplip that supports "HP DeskJet Ink Advantage 2300 All-in-One" is 3.20.5. 20.04 LTS ships with 3.20.3. I have a different model (HP Deskjet 2700) that also requires 3.20.5, so I had to purge 3.20.3 and install 3.20.5 manually following similar instructions to what you link, then, I installed the plugin and was able to scan using xsane.

Regarding dependencies, look out that you are not using python2 instead of python3. I installed hplip after a fresh Ubuntu install and it compiled stuff for python2 instead of python3. It is essential to install "python-is-python3" before hplip and the plugin, otherwise, missing extension errors start to appear (cupsext.so in my case). I was able to print on that "broken installation" by adding the printer with CUPS, but to make the scanner work I had to re-install hplip after fixing the python situation.

A brute force alternative is to upgrade to 20.10, that comes with hplip 3.20.11, and manually install the corresponding plugin on top of the correctly packaged version.

Comment: but still, I can't find my all in one, printer+scanner 2336 via this application...

Comment: I believe the "2300" driver covers all the series, that is, all 23xx models, including yours.

Comment: can you check this out? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWox4TF8J10

Answer (score 0):

(Issue fixed) (My OS version is Ubuntu 18.04)
My printer was working but scanner was not working.

Then I downloaded hp drivers by selecting the model number from the following link.Here my printer model is hp-laser-mfp-138.

https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laser-mfp-130-printer-series/24494378/model/24494406

extracted the files and executed the following commands.

sh install.sh

sh install-scanner.sh

Now able to scan without any issue.