# scanner found in terminal and in simplescan, but does not work for xsane in simplescan or gimp, says "unable to connect to scanner"

Tags: scanner

scanner found in terminal and in simplescan, but does not work for xsane in simplescan or gimp, says “unable to connect to scanner”

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x03f0 [Hewlett-Packard], product=0x332a [HP Color LaserJet Pro 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 03f0:332a Hewlett-Packard 

roger@roger-desktop:~$ sane-find-scanner
found USB scanner (vendor=0x03f0 [Hewlett-Packard], product=0x332a [HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M177fw]) at libusb:003:003

roger@roger-desktop:~$ scanimage -L
device `hpaio:/usb/HP_Color_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M177fw?serial=CNG6J1J7WD' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_Color_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M177fw all-in-one

roger@roger-desktop:~$ scanimage -T
scanimage: open of device hpaio:/usb/HP_Color_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M177fw?serial=CNG6J1J7WD failed: Error during device I/O

roger@roger-desktop:~$ scanimage -V
scanimage (sane-backends) 1.0.27; backend version 1.0.27
```

---> Scan used to work ok, but some time ago
---> Works fine for printing.

Comment: Please provide OS & release details.  You mention it worked some time ago, why? what changes occurred in the mean time? (same OS/release? same programs accessing it? etc)   Please also provide an actual question (title may not be visible on all devices when viewing page so your description text should be complete; ie. detail in title repeated!)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or)

Comment: - Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, 15.6 GiB, Intel® Core™ i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8, AMD® Verde, 3.28.2, 64-bit. disk 967.5 GB

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you dispense with using HPLIP and its non-free plugin and employ a more modern method for scanning. This technique is employed *by default* on Ubuntu 21.04 so you could get packages from its archive. However, it is probably more convenient and reliable to do the following:

- Go [here](https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan) (main page), read and move on to [this page](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_18.04/amd64/) (Debian packages).
- Download and install **sane-airscan** and **ipp-usb**.
- Plug the device into USB and execute `scanimage -L`. The output should show an entry beginning with `device 'airscan:...`.
- Check scanning with `simple-scan airscan:..`.

**Further info**

- Downloading and installing sane-airscan and ipp-usb id linked from the main page under *Installation from pre-build binaries*.
- HPLIP becomes [redundant.](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting#ipp-usb)
- WiFi is [not necessary](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting#ippoverusb) to use sane-airscan.
- AirScan uses the [eSCL protocol](https://wiki.debian.org/SaneOverNetwork#escl)

Comment: Can you please give full detail on how to download and install sane-airscan and ipp-usb? Can I do this with Synaptic Package Manager, or ?

I presume no need to remove HPLIP, etc ?

Does "airscan" have any meaning other than just a name? That machine does not have wi-fi.

Thanks!

Comment: @Roger Davis I have added to my answer.

Comment: I don't see "HP_Color_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M177fw" in the supported list at https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan .  I assume you know it works for that one, so which of the two "HP_Color_LaserJet_Pro_M  xxx" should I use?  Or do I just install it and it will go with what works ?  And I presume that installed software will use the "SANE" choice as it always has?

Comment: The M177 has not yet been reported as working with `sane-airscan`. **You are the tester**. A report may be submitted here or as an issue at the website.

Comment: Lots of response. Lots of correct information. Zero feedback form @Roger Davis. This hardly helps other users.

Comment: Can Synaptic be used to install these?

Comment: Yes. Indeed Synaptic can be used .

Comment: When I search for ipp-usb and saane-airscan, Synaptic places them n the left column, but won't select them, like they aren't found.  Do I need to add a repository, or permission, or ???

Comment: Have you read the first item under **Further info** in my answer? There is a link to follow that gives detailed instructions on how to add a repository.

Comment: I already found the place to add a repository, but the question is what repository?  
Alternately, can I simply use
''' sudo apt-get install sane-airscan '''
'''' sudo apt-get install ipp-usb '''
Thanks!

Comment: @Roger Davis I have lost interest in this topic. All you had to do was to go to a site and download and install two packages. What's the problem in that? You add the repository for your distribution, 20.04 etc.

Comment: I'm sorry that you have little patience for my need for detail. I can only access the problem machine for a few hours every two or three days, and I'm slow because I'm unsure. While I've been using Ubuntu for a long time, I don't easily dive into Harry Potter incantations - I need strong and specific guidance. It's not lack of interest on my part, it's strong interest in not screwing things up worse.

I recognize you are an expert and dance through these details, but I can't. Perhaps you can refer me to someone who has more time for careful detail I need?

Comment: I need the specific commands needed to download, install, and provide for automatic updating of these packages as time passes, or be specific about hot to make them available to Synaptic, as they don't seem to be now ?

Comment: I thought I had it installed, by these instructions - but didn't work
For xUbuntu 16.04 run the following:

echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_16.04/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:pzz.list
curl -fsSL https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:pzz/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home_pzz.gpg > /dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt install sane-airscan

and then sudo apt install install ipp-usb

Comment: This didn't work - Simple Scan Failed to scan, unable to connect to scanner
For xUbuntu 18.04 run the following:

echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_18.04/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:pzz.list
curl -fsSL https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:pzz/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home_pzz.gpg > /dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt install sane-airscan

and then sudo apt install install ipp-usb

Comment: You do not need a repository. One can set uo later. I am going to assume you know how to download a file and that the file will go in the Downloads directory. `cd Downloads`. Check the files are there with `ls -l`. Then `apt install ./ipp-usb_0.9.19-1+50.1_amd64.deb` followed by `apt install ./sane-airirscan_0.99.26-1+86.1_amd64.deb`.

Comment: Typos. airirscan should airscan. op should be up.

Comment: I'll follow up as quickly as I can - Dr. appts over next few days...

Comment: No luck - Harry Potter not here... Tried every variation and sudo I could up with as well...  can't give complete into, limited characters - roger@roger-desktop:~$ apt install ./ipp-usb_0.9.19-1+50.1_amd64.deb
E: Unsupported file ./ipp-usb_0.9.19-1+50.1_amd64.deb given on commandline
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
roger@roger-desktop:~$ sudo apt install ./ipp-usb_0.9.19-1+50.1_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for roger: 
Reading package lists...Done

Comment: Voldemort curses me again - Found ipp-usb and airscan-unstable in Synaptic, tried it, got this - E: /var/cache/apt/archives/sane-airscan-unstable_1620822232-1+21.1_amd64.deb: trying to overwrite '/etc/sane.d/airscan.conf', which is also in package sane-airscan 0.99.26-1+86.1 - I need Dumbledore - HELP !!!

Comment: (Reading database ... 748874 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../sane-airscan_0.99.26-1+86.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking sane-airscan (0.99.26-1+86.1) over (0.99.26-1+86.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package sane-airscan-unstable.
Preparing to unpack .../sane-airscan-unstable_1620822232-1+21.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking sane-airscan-unstable (1620822232-1+21.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/sane-airscan-unstable_1620822232-1+21.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):

Comment: trying to overwrite '/etc/sane.d/airscan.conf', which is also in package sane-airscan 0.99.26-1+86.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/sane-airscan-unstable_1620822232-1+21.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up sane-airscan (0.99.26-1+86.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...

Comment: Tried again...
roger@roger-desktop:~$ scanimage -L
device `hpaio:/usb/HP_Color_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M177fw?serial=CNG6J1J7WD' is a Hewlett-Packard HP_Color_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M177fw all-in-one
device `airscan:w0:HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M177fw[538144]' is a WSD HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M177fw[538144] ip=192.168.1.157
roger@roger-desktop:~$ 
Still no scanning ...

Comment: Can you scan with `simple-scan "airscan:w0:HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M177fw[538144]"` ?

Comment: YES !!!  But the command must be entered twice, thusly:
---------------
roger@roger-desktop:~$ simple-scan "airscan:w0:HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M177fw[538144]
> simple-scan "airscan:w0:HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M177fw[538144]

(simple-scan:16458): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:13:42.867: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: Unable to register client
roger@roger-desktop:~$ 
----------------

Comment: 3rd time:@roger-desktop:~$ roger@roger-desktop:~$ simple-scan "airscan:w0:HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M177fw[538144]
> > simple-scan "airscan:w0:HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M177fw[538144]
roger@roger-desktop:~$: command not found
roger@roger-desktop:~$ 
roger@roger-desktop:~$ (simple-scan:16458): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:13:42.867: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: Unable to register client
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `:'
roger@roger-desktop:~$ roger@roger-desktop:~$ 
roger@roger-desktop:~$: command not found
roger@roger-desktop:~$

Comment: Tried this variation - no scan.  Simple-scan finds scanner, but gives error "unable to connect to scanner"

roger@roger-desktop:~$ simple-scan

(simple-scan:16819): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:30:36.950: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.SessionManager.AlreadyRegistered: Unable to register client

Comment: ALSO:
roger@roger-desktop:~$ airscan:w0:HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M177fw[538144]
airscan:w0:HP: command not found
roger@roger-desktop:~$

Comment: I did lots of cleanup and package checking today, and now it seems to work, but ONLY if I select WSD Airscan, which is only sometimes available.  True on Xsane, SimpleScan, and Gimp.