# Epson ET-2750 upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, usb, printing, epson

When I upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04LTS to Ubuntu 20.04LTS will my Epson ET-2750 printer setup from 18.04 upgrade to 20.04?

I could not install the Epson printer on 20.04 standalone. The only difficulty I could see was 20.04 would not accept USB as a connection; 18.04 did accept a USB connection.

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible issue with `ippusbxd`. Ubuntu 20.04LTS introduces `ippusbxd` as a default installed package to promote auto-detection and auto-installation (using `cups-browsed`) of a USB-connected device.

Unfortunately, its usefulness and reliability has become very questionable. So much so that it has been replaced by the much better `ipp-usb` on Ubuntu 21.04. Whether or not it is the problem in your case, you are advised:

- Switch off the device.
- Remove `ippusbxd` from the system.

Should auto-detection and auto-installatio still be an attractive proposition, the advice [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1354074/scanner-found-in-terminal-and-in-simplescan-but-does-not-work-for-xsane-in-simp) applies.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, ipp-usb is no better for my Epson ET-2750 than ippusbxd was. I upgraded from Ubuntu 20 LTS to 22 LTS and my Epson would no longer print. I found ipp-usb, removed it and installed lsb. I called up the printer settings, clicked on "additional printer settings", found my printer and installed it. I ran a test page and it was fine.

I don't know much about printer daemons, but it looks like ipp-usb, also known as ipp-over-usb, does just that, it ignores the Epson USB printer.

My concern would be an Epson usb printer and an ipp printer on the same machine; would lsb take precedence over ipp? I don't know.

Good luck.