# How to use HP MFP m125a for scanning with HP JetDirect 175x?

Tags: networking, usb, printing, hp, scanner

Configuration:

Kubuntu 20.04 with all updates
$ uname -a
Linux temo-Lenovo-T420 5.11.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 11 15:58:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comp: Lenovo T420, RAM 16, SSD 512 GB + HDD 1.5 GB

Small home network, router is "Residential Gateway" from provider, chinese Noname 813-G. 50 megabits FO link.

I've got HP LaserJer MFP m125a printer/scanner/copier with ONLY USB connection.

When connected to USB, it prints and scans perfectly using xsane or VueScan.

But I need access to it from my wife's note also (win7 Pro 64 bit), so I decided to connect it to network. I've got old HP JetDirect 175x, connected MFP to it by USB and then to router by wire.

Printing works well - no problems, but I couldn't scan - every try failed. Not sane/sxane, nor VueScan - device not found.

I tried everything, checked every possible solution with ZERO result.

All needed soft is installed. BTW, HPLIP Toolbox surprisingly cannot even see the printer and cannot print test page, even from System Settings it works.

Looking for any possible solution. Can anybody help or suggest anything?

Shortly:

- USB connection works 100% printer and scanner
- NET connection prints, but scan is not working.

P.S. Added by request from @brian_p:

root@temo-Lenovo-T420:/home/temo# lpstat -v
device for Hewlett-Packard_Hewlett-Packard_HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M125a: dnssd://HP%20LaserJet%20Pro%20MFP%20M125a%20(00110AC6E67C)._pdl-datastream._tcp.local/
device for HP-LaserJet-Pro-MFP-M125a: hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M125a?serial=CNB6H968YM
device for HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M125a: hp:/net/HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M125a?ip=192.168.1.200
device for HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M125a_2: hp:/net/HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M125a?ip=192.168.1.200

root@temo-Lenovo-T420:/home/temo# lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
...
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: A is your machine. N is the notebook. On A do `lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7`. On N do `lpstat -v`. Edit your first post to have the outputs.

Comment: Is A network-connected?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I install HPLIP binary/proprietary plugin/driver for my HP printer or printer+scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070470/how-should-i-install-hplip-binary-proprietary-plugin-driver-for-my-hp-printer-or)

Comment: @N0rbert I've seen it it did all suggested, it didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: @brian_p A and N is the same, there's only one Linux comp on network

root@temo-Lenovo-T420:/home/temo# lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
... many times

Comment: @brian_p
root@temo-Lenovo-T420:/home/temo# lpstat -v
device for Hewlett-Packard_Hewlett-Packard_HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M125a: dnssd://HP%20LaserJet%20Pro%20MFP%20M125a%20(00110AC6E67C)._pdl-datastream._tcp.local/
device for HP-LaserJet-Pro-MFP-M125a: hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M125a?serial=CNB6H968YM
device for HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M125a: hp:/net/HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M125a?ip=192.168.1.200
device for HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M125a_2: hp:/net/HP_LaserJet_Pro_MFP_M125a?ip=192.168.1.200